# Live Logging in Python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, cloud

I am currently working on a project and there is the need to log some user input and probably errors that will occur.
Currently I keep the logs in the log files and the user send them to me every (let's say) 2 days.
The upgrade I want to do, is log the necessary items-input-errors live. 
By live I mean, I want to upload in real-time the logs of the users in a cloud-based repository like Google Drive, Onedrive etc.
Does anyone have any idea how to implement this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google docs actually has an api to modify documents and sheets live. Also with a python implementation.

- [Google docs api python](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)
- [Google sheets api python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- [reading writing data on spreadsheet.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)